# Bones not moving mesh anymore

Tags: rigging

This was working fine, but I think I applied some modifiers and then was sculpting before I noticed the bones no longer move the mesh.

I have tried to recreate the armature modifier but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Bones problem]

How do I reattach the mesh to the rig?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For some reason your vertices are no longer assigned to any vertex groups, so the armature can't control them anymore, there may be a way to assign them back to the right vertex group and switch the armature to rest pose without messing the mesh, but what you can do is:

First reset the rotation of the armature <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, switch it to *Pose* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Pose as Rest Pose*, parent the character to the armature *With Automatic Weights*, give it the default pose you want, apply as rest pose again. You can symmetrize the mesh and also the armature.

Comment: "for some reason" ; it might be the applied modifiers mentioned by OP that change the mesh up to breaking point of vertex groups.

Comment: @ L0Lock, applying the modifier shouldn't remove the vertices though. Btw, do you know a better solution than the one I recommend? I can't find...

Comment: Oh i thought you meant the vertex groups were still there but empty. X) I'm on phone right now so I can't fully check by myself ; but your solution sounds good

Comment: Yes that's what I say, the character mesh still has vertex groups but they are empty, no vertices assigned to them, applying an Armature modifier shouldn't remove the vertices from the vertex groups

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. It didn't work for me when I quickly tried, but I had already solved the issue another way by then, so I didn't try very hard.